# Is there a way to automatically put my Android phone into silent mode while recharging?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, automation, silent-mode, alerts

Every night before sleep I usually put my Galaxy S4 into my bed's headboard to recharge, but every night I also get up because of the beep that the phone does when someone send something to my wazzup messenger.

It's not nice put it into silent mode before sleep and return from it every day, is there any way to do such ting automatically?

Comment: Do you want to silence it while charging, or just while you're sleeping?

Comment: When charging it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [Tasker](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/) for this ([Play Store link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm)). Tasker can create macros that are run on certain triggers, such as connecting the phone to a charger.

An example of the necessary programming can be found [here](http://tasker.wikidot.com/sleepmode). Check the link for additional info, but here's the necessary part:

```
Create Profile "Sleep Mode"

Add Context Power
    Source: AC    //You can also set this to all when you
                  //charge your phone using USB.

Add Context Time
    From: 22:00
    To: 07:00
    Repeat: Off

Add Start Task
1.  Silent Mode
    Mode: On
2.  Variable Set
    Name: %SLEEPMODE
    To: 1

Add Exit Task
1.  Silent Mode
    Mode: Off
2.  Variable Clear
    Name: %SLEEPMODE
```

Comment: Tasker is pretty much the default answer for any question that follows the format "Is there a way to have my device automatically do X if condition Y?" :D

Comment: Yupp, it is. And in onik's example, one could even ommit the exit task: Tasker then would automatically revert to the settings active immediately before the profile triggered.

Comment: tasker is a paid app, there isn't any free solution?

Comment: @Diogo There are [quite a few](http://android.appstorm.net/roundups/utilities-roundups/tasker-alternatives-to-automate-your-android/).

Comment: I like @Nick's answer; Silence@Power is much simpler than this answer, as it does exactly what's being asked for and nothing more.

Answer (score 3):

I used to have the same boring procedure every night. Plug in the power cable to recharge the phone and turn sounds off manually. So I decided to create an app to automate this procedure. 
With this app, user can define the time interval within the app is active (eg. 23:00 up to 6:00am) as well as the appropriate actions to be taken when user plugs in or unplugs the device from the power cord. You can mute not only the call ring tones but also the sms/social network/emails notifications.

The application does not require many resources as it's triggered only on power cord plug in/out and on specific times.  On Android 5+ muting is in form of "Do not disturb" mode, which means that user can allow some important contacts (eg. favorites) to disturb the silence. (See the phone setting for this mode).

It's called Silence@Power and you can give it a try on Play Store [(play store link)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nick.nikitaris.silenceatpower)

Answer (score 1):

reopening an old thread as I lost this feature and could not for the life of me remember how it was provided after I did a factory reset.

Sony has an app called smart connect for use with their smart phones and other bits and bobs they make, its free and you don't need to use it for anything else.

When you plug your phone in at night it gives you a host of options so you can mute apps and allow calls or just tell everyone to go away until morning.

Hope it helps someone

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware&hl=en_GB

Answer (score 1):

You can use the free/paid version of [AutomateIt](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=AutomateIt.mainPackage) or [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) for the desired automation.

### AutomateIt

1. Rule for enabling silent mode:

   - Trigger: Power Connected Trigger
   - Action: Set Sound Mode Action → Silent (No Vibrate)
   - Rule Details: No
2. Rule for disabling silent mode:

   - Trigger: Power Disconnected Trigger
   - Action: Set Sound Mode Action → Normal (With/No Vibrate)
   - Rule Details: No

You can  set  time based triggers in coordination with power triggers using Composite actions trigger, you need to unlock it though.

### MacroDroid

1. Macro for enabling silent mode:

   - Trigger: Power Connected/Removed → Power Connected
   - Action: Set Priority Mode → None | Vibrate Enable/Disable → Silent (Vibrate On)
   - Constraint:  None | Time constraint
   - Name: Quiet!
2. Macro for disabling silent mode:

   - Trigger: Power Connected/Removed → Power Disconnected
   - Action: Set Priority Mode → All | Vibrate Enable/Disable → Normal
   - Constraint:  None | Time constraint
   - Name: Go loud!